# Block visible only to the user who created it

Tags: blocks

Is there any module that allows a block to be seen only by the user who created it, and not to any user with the same role?

Comment: I'm not even really sure what's being asked here.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

You can use block visibility settings PHP code to check for specific users.

Please find the sample php code below.

```
<?php
global $user;
$allowed = array('moderator','administrator'); // Allowed Roles
$allowed_uids = array(1, 5, 10); // 1, 5, 10 are user id's which you want to allow
$valid=FALSE;
foreach($user->roles as $role){
  if(in_array($role, $allowed) && in_array($user->uid, $allowed_uids)) {       
    $valid=TRUE;
  }
}
return $valid;
?>
```

See the screen show below where you need to write above code.

[image]

Comment: +1.. I too was wondering about the scenario. Nice way to do it. Just a small remark, it is [recommended](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/global-keyword-vs-globals-superglobal-271541.html) to use `$GLOBALS['user'];` rather than `global $user;` to ensure the value of the variable doesn't change outside the function block.

Comment: The OP is asking for the block to be visible only to the user who created it, and not to other users with the same role.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any module that shows the block only to the user who created it.

Drupal doesn't record who has created a block. Even supposing a module would record such information to decide who can view a block, that module would not be much useful, as the user who can add a new block in a Drupal site are already restricted to the users with the permission to administer blocks, which is not a permission you normally give to any user with an account on a Drupal site.